# Bordered Text Heading with Top Margin Within Image-Covered Header Tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, margin

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/888qtapo/1/).

I am trying to create an image-covered header that responsively fills the visible portion of the window. The problem I am having is that when I attempt to put a top margin on my `<h1>` tag the image gets pushed down, too.

How could I fix this? Is there a better alternative to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

**EDIT:** I think I've solved it. Inspired by a couple comments below, I was able to do some re-arranging and turns out I did need some padding after all. I just needed it in a different place. Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/888qtapo/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edit. I changed the CSS to this , and it worked.

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 2em sans-serif;position:relative;
    border: 5px solid;
    margin: 16px; margin-top:100px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 68%;
}
```

Comment: But then my left and right margins (currently set to 'auto') are nullified. I need it to be perfectly centered on the page.

Comment: Edited it ^. If it worked, please upvote and tick the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution without using JS

**HTML**

```
<header class="head">
     <h1>Heading</h1>

</header>
<div class="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
body{background:#ccc}
header.head{background:#0f0}
.container {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080/') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 2em sans-serif;
    border: 5px solid;
    margin: 16px auto;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 68%;
    margin-top:30px; //set whatever margin you need 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/888qtapo/2/)

Comment: What are the advantages and/or disadvantages to applying the background to an empty `<div>` as opposed to applying it directly to the `<html>` or `<body>` tags?

Comment: Also @Nadeemmnn, in your demo you don't have the heading sitting atop the background... and you have to change the page's background color to match. I want the text to be right on top of my image.

Comment: 1. background can be applied to html or body no issues with that   2. No scripting involved on resize or setting default height calculation not required. what if javascript is disabled:)

Answer (score -1):

Why not using padding instead of margin?